# Is it possible to have a GitHub repo with two branches that contain different directories on my local machine?

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I have a jekyll site that I would like to have hosted on GitHub. Since jekyll plugins aren't supported on GitHub I was wanting to have my mater branch only contain the files inside _site and make a development branch that has everything else in it.

Would this be possible? If so how could I do it? I am not the best with git.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that all you want is to have a development branch and a master branch which will contain a mirror of the content of some folder, say _site.

Let's do this!
Okay. I assume you have a repository with a development branch which contains all staff and `_site` folder you want to "export".

Lets create a commit which contains just **the content** of the `_site` folder.

`echo 'Fill with a meaningful description' | git commit-tree development^{tree}:_site` creates a commit and outputs its id. It was `47651a42...`. It **will be** different on your machine.

Note that `development^{tree}:_site` is a revision (sha1 sum) of the tree which corresponds to the `_site` folder in the root of the last commit on the `development` branch.

And now make **master** branch point to this commit:
`git update-ref refs/heads/master 47651a42`

Now `git log master` show the following on my machine

```
commit 47651a42e6800f399c4352d0416f4ca96895f099
Author: Aleksandr Priymak <aleksandr.priymak@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jul 27 05:27:43 2012 +0400

    first commit
```

If you checkout this branch you get the content of the _site folder! That's simple. There is only one thing left. `47651a42` commit doesn't have any parents so you will need to add `-f` to your `git push` command to push updated master. The other way around is to actually specify the parent. To do this use this command

`echo 'Fill with a meaningful description' | git commit-tree dev^{tree}:_site -p $(cat .git/refs/heads/master)`

You can do this using the following one-liner

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master $(echo 'Add commit message here!' | git commit-tree dev^{tree}:_site -p $(cat .git/refs/heads/master))
```

Comment: I did something similar to this except I don't want to actually have _site in the master repo I just want the contents and when I ran `git add _site/*` I figured I would get that but it actually added _site as well as its contents.

Would it just be simpler to have two git repos one inside _site and one inside myusername.github.com directory with a .gitignore _site?

Comment: Yeah, it will be simpler, but you lost the information about based on what data the _site was generated unless you use submodules.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. What do you mean?

Comment: All I have to say is how? Haha thank you so much that worked like a charm. I put those three commands in my README so I can do this right. I have purposefully never worked with different branches because I always tend to screw things up. Thanks again for your help. It is people like you that make stackoverflow and other places like it a better community.

Comment: `$ git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages $(echo 'Add commit message here!' | git commit-tree master^{tree}:_site -p $(cat .git/refs/heads/gh-pages))  
**fatal: Not a valid object name master^{tree}:_site**`. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @VladimirStarkov do you have _site folder?

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak yes ![image](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/3118/4fb186b702f14566ad746e1.png)

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Can you use multi-step instructions. Now it looks like your current directory is not a repository root. Or maybe you don't have hg-page (though it does not explain the second error). It hard to debug bash one-liners